# openconnect nexthop has invalid gateway and invalid values for route get request

Tags: arch-linux, openconnect

I am trying to connect to my university network with openconnect. When I do, it asks for my credentials and then outputs the following:

```
POST university_url
Got CONNECT response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
CSTP connected. DPD 30, Keepalive 20
Connected as my.ip.v4.address, using SSL, with DTLS in progress
Established DTLS connection (using GnuTLS). Ciphersuite (DTLS1.2)-(ECDHE-RSA)-(AES-256-GCM).
Error: Nexthop has invalid gateway.
Error: ipv4: Invalid values in header for route get request.
```

on arch linux. Cisco anyconnect works fine on a ubuntu vm on the very same machine (clumsy workaround), however I would rather resolve the cause of the issue. This is unfortunately beyond my skilllevel. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is because of added validation to `ipconnect2` (which provides the `ip` utility) in version 5.x (Not sure which version specifically)

`vpnc-script`, which is used by openconnect, builds CIDR IPv4 addresses and sends them to the `ip` utility for routing. `ip` at version 4.x ignores the netmask length information, but `ip` at version 5.x regards it as invalid.

I used the [downgrade](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/downgrade/) AUR package to bring my `ipconnect2` to version 4.20, which seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Mandjaro Linux and the problem is gone after I upgraded the [vpnc](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?name=vpnc) package manually to version 0.5.3.r468.r81-1.